# Is there a difference between and vs AND

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle10g

I was reading somewhere that `and` is a bitwise operator and `AND` is a regular operator?

Like the following:

```
AND is equivalent to &&
and is equivalent to &
```

Is this right? I tried searching on stack overflow, but I can find anything because using the word and to search lead no where. Can someone link a question, I am sure this has been asked here before.

Comment: No there isn't. Surely trivial to test them both anyway.

Comment: `and` and `AND` mean the same thing in SQL: *logical AND*. Bitwise operators are completely separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is not case sensitive, at least for keywords

Answer (score 0):

no both are the same it's just a **[convention](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SqlCodingStyle)** to write the key words capitalized

here is an example

```
SELECT id,name 
FROM table_name 
WHERE id 
IN (1,2)
AND name = 'username'
```

is equivalent to

```
select id,name
from table_name
where id
in (1,2)
and name = 'username'
```

and as you can see better for readability

Comment: Not necessarily a good convention, or a widely respected one, of course

Comment: as i mentioned before "just a convention" but **I** find it better for readability